# Помогите разобраться с url в i18n

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Пишу блог на Python Django. Занимаюсь переводом с помощью i18n.
В проекте несколько приложений. Во втором приложении url'ы строятся так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне хотелось бы так:

> localhost:8000/blog/en

Содержимое файла urls.py:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]